# Fixed width of plotly graph

Tags: python, plotly

I'm setting the width and height of my plots with

```py
fig.update_layout(width=500, height=500)
```

Unfortunately, this produces differently sized plots, depending on the width of the labels, as seen below.

[image]

However, I do not find a way to produce equally sized plots.

```py
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(...))
```

Neither `add_trace` nor `go.Scatter` allows setting the width. Is there a way I'm overlooking?

MVE:

```
    fig = go.Figure()
    fig.update_layout(width=500, height=500)
    for i, data in enumerate(data_list):
        fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=data['x'], y=data['y'], name='some_label'))
```

Comment: How are you making the subplots? Could you share more code?

Comment: @aerijman Added some code. But I don't use subplots, I manually put them together for the comparison.

Answer (score 3):

A workaround is specifying a position inside the limits of the plot in the layout, like this:

```
fig.update_layout(legend=dict( 
    yanchor="bottom", 
    y=0.8, 
    xanchor="right", 
    x=1 
    ))
```

Where ***y* starts in 0.8**

With this complete code I get the images shown below:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go 
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots     

df = pd.DataFrame({
     'x':np.arange(1,10), 
     'y':np.array([1,2,4,8,16,32,64,128,256]),
     'y2':np.random.randint(0,100,9)
     })

fig1 = go.Figure() 
fig1.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df['x'], y=df['y2'], name='short_legend')) 
fig1.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df['x'], y=df['y'], name='short_legend_B')) 
fig1.update_layout(width=500, height=500) 


fig2 = go.Figure() 
fig2.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df['x'], y=df['y2'], name='loooooooooooooooooong_legend')) 
fig2.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df['x'], y=df['y'], name='loooooolololololololoong_legend_B')) 
fig2.update_layout(width=500, height=500)
```

First row is without updating the layout as mentioned above. Below is updating the layout.[image]

Comment: Nice idea.  Or perhaps adding the legend to the bottom on the graphs, so data is not covered.

Comment: I tried in the top and the data is covered, though... I was wondering if you programatically set the scale to allow extra-space... perhaps helps...